# Why Node not found when running react-scripts?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Created a default `create-react-app` project. And tried to run it `yarn start`. Tried to run it in `cmd`, `powershell`.
And getting an error:
**my-app/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: node: not found**

This is the problematic line in the script: 
`node  "$basedir/../react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js" "$@" <-- node not found`

I checked my PATH vars and set a high priority for **C:\Program Files\nodejs**
Reinstalled node.js and installed a different version 12.14

UPDATE:
If I run it in `bash` it works properly. But still, though need to solve it on other terminals

Comment: What do you see if you run the command `node` or `node --version` on the console (CMD / PowerShell)?

Comment: @Dominik  v12.14.0

Comment: if you are on windows, you must restart your computer before you start using it in all the terminals. see if are able to display the node version in the terminal you are trying to use. next, create a new react project and see if it works. eliminate and isolate if the issue is node or react.then proceed.

Comment: No, a computer restart is not necessary. But you should restart your terminal / console if you change environment variables from another terminal or UI. For example: Restart VSCode if you use the terminal inside. Or just close the terminal and reopen.

Comment: @Jay that's exactly what I did. Didn't quite understand what you meant by isolating the issue

Comment: @Dominik tried it

Comment: isolating means, like, trying different steps and see where the issue might be. if you are able to get the node version to display (on the terminal where issue is coming) then node is fine. move on to troubleshoot react native. create a new project. another thing to try is create a simple node server using express and see if it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had installed WSL and somehow it was running in that environment and there wasn't Node installed there. So I removed WSL and now it runs okay.